# Cubemap texture with bitmap in OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

When I create a cubemap texture with simple colors, this works well:

```
@JvmStatic
fun createSimpleTextureCubemap() {
    val textureId = IntArray(1)
    val cubeFace0 = byteArrayOf(127, 127, 127) 
    val cubeFace1 = byteArrayOf(0, 127, 0) 
    ... // create other cube faces with simple color

    val cubeFaces = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(3)
    glGenTextures(1, textureId, 0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureId[0])

    cubeFaces.put(cubeFace0).position(0)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, 
        1, 1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, cubeFaces)

    cubeFaces.put(cubeFace1).position(0)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, 
        1, 1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, cubeFaces)
    ...
    return textureId[0]
}
```

But when I try to create a cubemap texture with bitmap:

```
@JvmStatic
fun createTextureCubemap(context: Context, rowID: Int) {
    val input = context.resources.openRawResource(rowID)
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)

    val textureId = IntArray(1)
    glGenTextures(1, textureId, 0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureId[0])

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, bitmap, 0)
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, bitmap, 0)
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, bitmap, 0)
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, bitmap, 0)
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, bitmap, 0)
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, bitmap, 0)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    return textureId[0]
}
```

Then the object turns black. Someone may suggest why the cubemap with the bitmap does not work (black color)?

Thanks for any comment/answer.

Comment: Are the dimensions of your bitmap square and a power-of-two?

Comment: @Columbo It was not a square). Thank You!!! You really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textures for Cubemaps need to be square. As mentioned in the comments, the bitmap used was not square.

From [glTexImage2D reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) (`GLUtils.texImage2D` is a convenience wrapper around `glTexImage2D`)

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if target is one of the six cube map 2D image targets and the width and height parameters are not equal.